# Code seems repeated, except for the callback function

Tags: javascript

I've written some JavaScript code:

```
  app.get('/offers/', function(req, res){
    var funcGetOffers = utils.funcGetOffers;
    var options = {top_sort: true};
    funcGetOffers(function(offers){
      res.render('offers', { offers:offers });
    }, options);
  });

  app.get('/api/get_offers', function(req, res){
    var funcGetOffers = utils.funcGetOffers;
    var options = {top_sort: true};
    funcGetOffers(function(offers){
      res.json(offers);
    }, options);
  });
```

The code is almost the same, and only the callback function is different.  I want to get rid of the repeat code, but didn't find a good way.

`funcGetOffers` is a long function which gets a list of items from the database:

```
var funcGetOffers = function(callback, opt) {
  var order = [['updatedAt', 'DESC']];
  var where = {};
  if (opt && opt.top_sort) {
    order.unshift(['flag_top', 'DESC']);
  }
  var Offer = models.offer;
  Offer.findAll({order:order}).success(function(offers){
    // some calc with offers
    // callback
    callback(offers);
  });
}
```

---

Thank @Flambino make me more clear, I did some change to `funcGetOffers` to make it promisily, now the code:

```
var options = {top_sort: true};

utils.funcGetOffers(options).then(function(offers){
  res.render('offers', { offers:offers });
});

utils.funcGetOffers(options).then(function(offers){
  res.json(offers);
});
```

changed the `funcGetOffers` signature, use a bluebird to make it promisily.

`utils.funcGetOffers(options).then(res.json)` didn't work by the promise, but looks much better now!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the local `funcGetOffers` variable. Just call `util.funcGetOffers` directly.

You may extract the `options` to a var outside the request handlers, since it's the same in both places.

After that, there's not really any repetition left. Sure, the 2 request handlers each call `utils.funcGetOffers`, but the callbacks are so different that it'd be more complex to generalize them.

However, you can skip the callback function expression for the `/api/get_offers` handler, and simply use `res.json` directly.

```
var options = { top_sort: true }; // maybe call this offersOptions to make it clearer

app.get('/offers/', function(req, res){
  utils.funcGetOffers(function(offers){
    res.render('offers', { offers:offers });
  }, options);
});

app.get('/api/get_offers', function(req, res){
  utils.funcGetOffers(res.json, options);
});
```

I don't think it's necessary to do anything more elaborate than that.

---

And again, in `utils.funcGetOffers` you don't need all those local variables (you can access `models.offer` directly, and `where` isn't even used), and you can skip the success-callback, and just use the given one directly

```
var funcGetOffers = function(callback, opt) {
  var order = [['updatedAt', 'DESC']];
  if(opt && opt.top_sort) {
    order.unshift(['flag_top', 'DESC']);
  }
  models.offer.findAll({order:order}).success(callback);
}
```

---

In general, I'd recommend a bit more consistency. You obviously have a column named `updatedAt` (camelCase), but you apparently also have one called `flag_top` (underscored). Pick one way of naming things, and stick with it (for JavaScript, the convention is to use camelCase).

This extends to the options object (or `opts`, but there's no need to shorten it: Just call it `options`). There you have a key called `top_sort`, which should probably be camelCased - especially since you're not using it directly, but "translating" it to mean `flag_top`. In fact, it might be smarter to simply use the actual column name, rather than the - pretty ambuiguous - name `top_sort`.

And it'd be wise to handle errors too - not just `success`.

Lastly, there's really no need for the `func` prefix. If something's called `getOffers` it's implied that it's a function.

Comment: Thank you for your advise! very helpful! I tried Promise pattern, I think it makes the function looks better.